# Toggle an Accordion with JQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion

I had an accordion given to me that is not toggling each tab open and close.  It only closes the tab when *another* title is selected, but I'd like the ability for the user to close it on click as well. I'm not sure how to edit this Jquery to allow this to happen.

```
jQuery("ul.gdl-accordion li").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).children(".accordion-content").css('height', function(){ 
        return jQuery(this).height(); 
    });
    if(jQuery(this).index() > 0){
        jQuery(this).children(".accordion-content").css('display','none');
    }else{
        jQuery(this).find(".accordion-head-image").addClass('active');
    }       

    jQuery(this).children(".accordion-head").bind("click", function(){
        jQuery(this).children().addClass(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).hasClass("active")) return "";
            return "active";
        });
        jQuery(this).siblings(".accordion-content").slideDown();
        jQuery(this).parent().siblings("li").children(".accordion-content").slideUp();          jQuery(this).parent().siblings("li").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

I'm assuming it's somewhere in the `.click` function, in that `if` statement... but I'm not sure why.

I'm also not sure why it is defaulting the first tab as open... is there a way to modify that as well?

http://jsfiddle.net/FKAAM/

Any advice is greatly appreciated.  Many thanks SO.

Comment: Before you loose your fingers writing "jQuery" all over the place: `(function($){ /*remap $ to jQuery*/ /*CODE HERE with bulletproof $ */ })(jQuery);`

Comment: I didn't code it, so yes, normally I wouldn't manually write out JQuery every time.  Also, @ashley, your solution was in fact correct, so thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use slideToggle() instead:

```
jQuery(this).siblings(".accordion-content").slideDown();

jQuery(this).siblings(".accordion-content").slideToggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FKAAM/4/

Comment: I like this solution, except the slide effect ceases to work after the 1st click.  It works if you use `.slideToggle()` instead.  http://jsfiddle.net/FKAAM/3/  Please revise answer.

Comment: Sorry, it should be slideToggle() instead of toggle(): http://jsfiddle.net/FKAAM/4/

Answer (score 2):

here's the acordion [link](https://jsfiddle.net/commanderDoge/191qffeo/) and full jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //you can now use $ as your jQuery object.
  $(".panel-heading").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active').find('.panel-body').slideToggle('fast');
    $(".panel-heading").not(this).parent().removeClass('active').find('.panel-body').slideUp('fast');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
collapsible: true
```

to your accordion options, then users will be able to click to close it.

(jQuery UI Accordion: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: I thought you were using the jQuery UI accordion: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/
You may want to look at that since it does everything needed already.

Answer (score -2):

I will suggest you to use jQuery accordion

```
$(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
```

Check the [example here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible). I guess this is what you needed.