# Overlapping toggle issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlapping

I'm trying to build this piece of code in jQuery and i was hoping you could help me! So:

I have some content that is to be hidden, and when i click a div the content shows up. so far no problem. The catch is that i wanted this to happen but with multiple classes and divs with the same class kind of like in the following format

Div.class

-Hidden Content.class_other

Div.class

-Hidden Content.class_other

Div.class

-Hidden Content.class_other

Div.class

-Hidden Content.class_other

When I would click a Div.class only the Hidden Content.class_other that's "inside it" (like sibling?) would show, and not any other. And if that one if being shown and I ought to click in some other Div.class, it's containing content would then show, and the one that was shown would collapse, I feel i am being too confusing...

here is the code i have so far for the job i need

```
<div class="dropdown1">click</div>
<div class="series">bla bla</div>
<div class="dropdown2">also click</div>
<div class="trofeu">bla bla</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.series , .trofeu').hide();

$('.dropdown1').click(function() {

$('.series').slideToggle();

});

$('.dropdown2').click(function() {

$('.trofeu').slideToggle();

});

});
```

And a [Pen](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/JoyreB) with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you did something like this?  you can mess around with different html markup too.  just adjust the jquery

```
<div id="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li>
                <h3>first title</h3>

            <div class="row">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Aliquam.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
                <h3>some title</h3>

            <div class="row">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor Aliquam.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
                <h3>sometitle2</h3>

            <div class="row">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
                <h3>some title3</h3>

            <div class="row">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut tincidunt risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam id venenatis tortor, a bibendum augue. Sed magna turpis, facilisis in posuere auctor, aliquam eget mauris. Integer non lectus at risus elementum auctor. Aliquam.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and then the jquery would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#dropdown li h3").click(function () {
         var $parent = $(this).parent();
         if ($parent.hasClass('active')) return;

         $("#dropdown ul .row").not().slideUp();
         $(this).next().slideDown(function () {
             $parent.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: but like that everything shows up from the begining :\

Comment: remove the active state  from <li class="active">

Comment: right. add css (or this can be done with jquery) 
#dropdown .row {
    display: none;
}

Comment: Ok this is pretty good! just one more thing, when i click a content to be shown and i like, i click the First title div to show the content, how do i make it so if i click it again the content hides? .toggle() effect. i dont completly understand your jquery…

Comment: you'll need to style it with your own css attributes.  codepen is adding it's own css...

Comment: but in your jquery you have a slideUp and aslideDown isnt there a way to change it to a slideToggle on click of the div#dropdown?

Comment: maybe this will help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202010/toggle-an-accordion-with-jquery)