# Is there any accordion for JQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I need to use a panel with a summarize text in it and a button below it. When I click the button the panel expand and more text appear and the button change it appearance and located below the text.
You can see the image:
[image: accordion alike I need] 
I found some threads about JQuery and accordion like: [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202010/toggle-an-accordion-with-jquery) or maybe [other website](http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/accordion.html), but it doesn't have the functionality I'm looking for.

Is there any other known pattern to do it or I need to write it?

Comment: FYI - this is **expand/collapse**, not `accordion`.  An [accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) works by expanding one area and collapsing all others... like.. well... how can I put this... an [accordion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion)!

Comment: Actually you right... and that's why I didn't find the answer I was looking for. I looked at only 1 panel while I should look about multiple panels...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that simply using a small script right?

```js
$(function () {
  $(".see-more").hide();
  $(".see-more-trigger").click(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.prev(".see-more").slideToggle(function () {
      if ($this.prev(".see-more").is(":visible"))
        $this.html("&#x25B2;");
      else
        $this.html("&#x25BC;");
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 0 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi hic perspiciatis corporis explicabo, aperiam veritatis impedit natus et voluptatum quas facere dolores nam enim illo harum dolore recusandae tenetur reiciendis!
  <br /><span class="see-more">Ad, facere illo, minima ipsa facilis voluptatibus provident expedita quos in, dignissimos earum vitae consequuntur blanditiis optio sed porro nostrum a soluta corporis. Culpa, non, ipsa. Deserunt, vitae, magni! Alias. Esse cum inventore amet enim odio deleniti, saepe, cumque quasi ducimus sunt consequuntur obcaecati consequatur sequi hic ut maiores eius quae vel nemo aut atque similique, nobis eligendi labore. Praesentium.</span><a href="#" class="see-more-trigger">&#x25BC;</a>
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia unde, laborum cum asperiores minima sed modi laboriosam architecto nam sapiente. Voluptate commodi, accusantium explicabo vitae, ex dolore quia minima esse.
  <br /><span class="see-more">Eum facilis repudiandae qui dolor voluptatum itaque amet, fuga ducimus velit dolorem, animi eaque quia officiis fugit officia saepe ea, dolore. Itaque molestias vitae, velit, hic impedit ipsa quaerat illum! Ut consequatur fugiat voluptatem libero quis sequi voluptas architecto fuga dolor voluptates nihil minus quidem distinctio natus nam quam totam tenetur eius ullam, necessitatibus harum, quod corporis perferendis enim. Culpa.</span><a href="#" class="see-more-trigger">&#x25BC;</a>
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error est amet iure aliquam iste autem quod ipsa ab harum illo, saepe fugit possimus obcaecati accusantium cumque optio repudiandae itaque facilis.
  <br /><span class="see-more">Enim illo ad, tenetur, ipsum id corporis minima, voluptatum fugit, nihil explicabo maiores unde! Id eveniet, pariatur, quis qui beatae ipsa. Vel recusandae numquam reiciendis, dolorem ipsam tempora dolorum perspiciatis! Rerum, explicabo dicta quos, optio pariatur, cum expedita cumque et ratione recusandae voluptatum quis fuga veniam fugit nemo! Cupiditate error omnis fugit ipsa, vero architecto corrupti. Provident ab, consequatur voluptate.</span><a href="#" class="see-more-trigger">&#x25BC;</a>
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit sed vero praesentium cumque libero inventore id optio eaque, totam vel at repellat. Dignissimos, in. Accusantium atque tempore, cupiditate earum quidem!
  <br /><span class="see-more">Omnis numquam quod veniam ratione explicabo, sequi iusto quibusdam ex, sunt tempora voluptatem nam inventore minima! Omnis, esse, impedit. Nobis debitis harum sed atque. Eveniet voluptate commodi quaerat velit aut! Quae quaerat dolorum quam optio vitae delectus, eligendi mollitia non inventore autem. Voluptate aperiam, natus necessitatibus optio iure! Neque fuga suscipit, maxime illo itaque ratione facere laboriosam ipsum delectus? Voluptatum.</span><a href="#" class="see-more-trigger">&#x25BC;</a>
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, ea! Veniam cum unde quia, aspernatur dolorum, mollitia fuga nisi debitis vitae eaque sapiente deserunt, eligendi maiores tempora magnam a reiciendis.
  <br /><span class="see-more">Id praesentium ea sit quae, sequi veritatis alias mollitia aspernatur animi atque eaque nesciunt aut ducimus sunt maxime non numquam magni dignissimos! Ducimus consequatur facere delectus adipisci saepe dolorum corporis. Iure inventore blanditiis sit ab maxime, fuga repellat dignissimos velit, quaerat cupiditate consequuntur iste mollitia ut alias non. Veritatis perspiciatis sint optio modi, esse perferendis culpa velit nostrum commodi maxime.</span><a href="#" class="see-more-trigger">&#x25BC;</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I saw an answer with "slideToggle" but it's not good because the image changes on the same location and I want it to be on bottom (where the text end).

Comment: @Dror Don't say you are a programmer if you comment like this. It took me a second to change the position. `:P`

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right... I'll do it. Thank you!

Comment: @Dror Yes buddy. I changed it long back. `:)`